# write() argument must be str, not bytes python

Tags: python, api

I am new to python. I got this pre written code that downloads data in to report. But I am getting the error

> "write() argument must be str, not bytes".

See below code

```
def _download_report(service, response, ostream):

    logger.info('Downloading keyword report')
    written_header = False
    for fragment in range(len(response.files)):
      file_request = service.reports().getFile(
        reportId=response.id_, reportFragment=fragment)
      istream = io.BytesIO(file_request.execute())

    if written_header:
      istream.readline()
    else:
      written_header = True
    ostream.write(istream.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to change the last line to

```
ostream.write(istream.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

PS. you may need to replace `'utf-8`` with whatever encoding the data is in

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate more on @sgDysregulation's answer:

One peculiarity with python 3 is that strings (`'hello, world'`) and binary strings (`b'hello, world'`) are basically incompatible. As an example, if you're familiar with basic file I/O, there are two types of modes to read a file in - you could use `open('file.txt', 'r')`, which returns unicode strings when you read from the file, or `open('file,txt', 'rb')`, which returns binary strings. The same applies for writing - you can't write strings correctly in mode `'wb'`, and can't write binary strings in mode `'w'`.

In this case, your `istream` returns binary strings when read from, whereas your `ostream` expects to write a unicode string. The solution is to change encoding from one to the other, and do what sgDysregulation recommends:

```
ostream.write(istream.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

this assumes that the binary string is encoded in utf-8 format, which it probably is. You might have to use a different format otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode the BytesIO object to get a string that can be written to the file:

```
ostream.write(istream.read().decode('utf-8'))
```